# Apply R glm predict function on dataframe by group

Tags: r, dataframe, function, glm

At the moment I am trying to apply GLM predict on a dataframe. The dataframe is quite large therefore I want to apply predict by chunks.

I have found a solution but it is quite unhandy. I first create an empty dataframe and then use rbind. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
df=data[c(),]
for (x in split(data, factor(sort(rank(row.names(data))%%10)))) {
     x["prediction"]=predict(model, x, type="response")
     df=rbind(df,x)
}
```

Comment: You haven't included a minimal. Could you do that? Also, what is your desired outcome? Meaning, what do you want to have in the final object `df`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mention, an example of what you want your output dataframe to look like would be very helpful.

But I think you can achieve what you want by making a grouping variable first then using 'group_by', something like this:

```
df <- data %>% 
  mutate(group = rep(1:10, times = nrow(.)/10)) %>% # make an arbitrary grouping factor for this example
  group_by(group) %>%  # group by whatever your grouping factor is
  summarise(predictions = predict(model, x, type = 'response')) # summarise could be replaced by mutate
```